# Are nested mercurial subrepos that bad?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

After researching mercurial and reading http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.devel/40107 I have been sufficiently warned about the dangers of nested subrepos. However, I have to use mercurial and subrepos seem like a useful tool. My issue is similar to [Hg sub-repository dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621670/hg-sub-repository-dependencies). My basic issue is this: I have a utilities repository that is used by many projects. Some of those projects are dependent on the utilities. It seems natural to have a project repository with a utilities subrepo nested under the main repository instead of 2 subrepos under a larger repository. This would make it easy to pull the correct version of the utilities subrepo if the projects need different versions.

I'm not sure I fully understand the problems from nesting subrepos as it seems like the best solution despite all the warnings.

Comment: So, I guess the actual question here is: As using a util subrepo nested under the main project repo is supposed to be bad, what bad things can actually happen?

Answer (score 0):

Nested suprepos are **not bad** per se, they just *doesn't supported by Bitbucket* without tricks (maybe by other Mercurial hostings also)